# Broken encoding while fetching data from sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I store the app data (cyrillic strings) in sqlite. When I try to display that data in the app I get strange characters instead of text. Here is how I get the data.

```
-(NSString *)getData
{
    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

    NSString *query = [NSString 
                       stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM users WHERE kind = '%@' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", self.kind ];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *selectedQuestion;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_step(statement);
        selectedQuestion =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);

    return selectedQuestion;
}
```

Comment: what happens if you change your query to: const char *query= "SELECT..... ";

Comment: I get Instance method -UTF8String not found (return type defaults to id) on line if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using UTF-8 and not UTF-16 sqlite databases, you're probably going to be happier using:

```
selectedQuestion = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];
```

And, the more general:

```
selectedQuestion = [NSString stringWithCString: (char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0) encoding: ENCODING];
```

can be used for other encodings that are NUL-safe.  For example replace ENCODING with NSUTF16StringEncoding for UTF16 (and there are variants for BE and LE versions if you know ahead of time and can't expect the marker to be there).

For encodings that are not NUL-terminated, you can use:

```
selectedQuestion = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: ptr  length: length encoding: ENCODING] autorelease];
```

where ptr and length have the location and length of the string and ENCODING, as above, indicates the ENCODING from the list of available encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a little bit on this party, but I solved this issue by saving the UTF16 data from a string in an sqlite3 blob type column.

Here's a sketch of what I did (minus error checking):

1) Create the table with the blob;

```
sqlite3_exec(database, "CREATE TABLE my_table (my_text BLOB NOT NULL);");
```

2) When inserting, be sure to prepare your statement with a blob:

```
// "text" is the NSString you want to save
sqlite3_stmt *w_statement = nil;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,"INSERT INTO my_table (my_text) VALUES (?);", -1, &w_statement,  NULL);
NSData *utf16Data = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
sqlite3_bind_blob(w_statement, 1, [utf16Data bytes], [utf16Data length], NULL);
sqlite3_step(w_statement);
```

3)  when reading:

```
// statement is your select statement
const void *textBytes = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 1);
NSData *textData = [NSData dataWithBytes:textBytes length:(sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 1))];
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:textData encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```